# How to save shared folders by Google Drive links in my account

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-sharing

For example someone emails you a link to a shared **folder** on Google Drive. Is there a way to add it in your Google Drive without downloading and uploading it manually?

It would be great if the owner/admin decides to delete the file I would still be able to use it.

The "make a copy" option only works for single file. So if there is a way creating single zip on Google Drive then the problem is solved.

Note: "transfer ownership" won't work because the two users are not from the same organization.

Answer (score 3):

While you can't do it at the folder level, the next best thing (which does not require downloading) is to select all and make a copy. This creates copies with you as an owner. Then, when you select just the copies, the submenu to organize>move to your own folder on your own Drive becomes available.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a way to do this. I could suggest a workaround with [this Google Drive add-on](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/transfer_files_ownership/631873519917):
"someone" should not email you a link to a shared folder on Google Drive, but should create a special link for transfer or copy a single file or folder from their Google Drive.

In this way, it is possible to transfer or copy Google Drive files to another organization (cross-domain).

Comment: let me try it!!

Comment: It;s easy enough:
1. Install the add-on from the Google Workspace Marketplace.
2. Open the side panel of the Google Drive in your browser.
3. Start the add-on "Transfer Files" from the side panel.
4. Authorize the add-on.
5. Select Google Drive objects.
6. Click the action Transfer or Copy.
7. Select "Create URL" action.
8. Set files recipient Google email or clear it.
9. Set "Valid until".
10. Send the URL to files recipient entered in step 8.

Comment: Thanks I followed the steps but it returns errors with red Exclamation mark on the left-hand-side. The error message is "invalid credential". Maybe I need to purchase a license?

Comment: I have given a sequence of steps for a scenario where one user transfers or copies files to another. However, they do not share their credentials. In this case, it is important that the account in step 8 matches the account in step 10, otherwise an access error will occur.
In step 8, you can remove the email, then the files can be accepted by any account.
If you have access to both accounts, then it's easier to use the webapp https://movefiles.app or select "Continue on this device" in step 7.
In any case, you can contact the developer on the add-on page in the Google Workspace Marketplace.

Comment: You should [edit] your answer to include all the relevant details rather than using comments.